# Make SMB on OS X more reliable

Tags: macos, smb

I'm having trouble with the SMB/Samba functionality in OS X (Lion, Mountain Lion):

1. It often takes forever to connect and mount
2. It often freezes on this progress dialog and it can't be closed, (x) button does simply nothing.
    
   [image: OS X SMB Connecting to Server]
3. It takes a few seconds even if the drive is already mounted and the connection is up.
    
   [image: OS X SMB share icon]
   I would expect it opens the mounted directory immediately.
4. Every click on mounted directory sidebar item in Finder means reconnecting to server or something like that – it also takes a few seconds to list a share
    
   [image]
5. A directory listings in already opened Finder windows, and share desktop icon does not **work after waking computer from sleep**. The connection apparently drops after a sleep and OS X doesn't reconnect, so I must remount the share manually (and close the new Finder window which is opened after making a connection).
6. If the SMB server become unavailable, **all Finder windows freeze**

There's no such issues with "Map network drive" feature in Windows... It needs to be set up only once, then it just works.

Is it possible to improve the SMB in OS X to the Windows level of SMB reliability?

Comment: For what it's worth, I got used to that. I have the same issues as you, except for no. 5. SMB on OS X has always been terribly bad. Switch to AFP if you can.

Comment: I can not share this opinion. We have several SMB-shares we connect to with MacOS-Clients and Never had one of these problems. Which SMB-Server are you running? And what about network-stability? We did find out that the Macs are a bit more sensitive to network-relatet issues than the windows clients.

Comment: My network is pretty stable and so my homeserver running Openmediavault (Debian distro) 24/7. My second SMB server is a common Win8 desktop. I have a macbook with OS X and Win8: SMB on Win works like a charm (one time setup), but on OS X, I must turn off WiFi to unmount drives, then turn WiFi on and remount drives over and over again...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're running Debian server, would you like to try NFS? It is supported by Mac/Win as well.

As for the issue, I'd suggest reviewing all Samba settings on the server and check for routing problems on your Mac computer. Logs are a good place to start.
http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080328110504281

Comment: Unfortunately NFS isn't an option because SMB (used also from Windows) uses precomposed unicode filenames, and NFS access files with decomposed unicode names so I can't access files with accents in filename with Finder. AFAIK Windows does not support NFS.